# run single unit tests for a module efficiently

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I wish all of you a happy new year! I want to write more unit tests in the new year, but how to handle it more easily? I found out to run tests while updating a module via `--test-enable` and `--stop-after-init` command line parameters. I have also read about `--test-file parameter`, but it does not work. This parameter is also not described in the docs.

How would you do TDD (test driven development)? In order to do that you have to be able to run tests quickly. Requiring to test the whole module with all its dependencies makes it impractical to write tests frequently. How to run a single unit test case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edited my own question from 'run single unit test case'. This command works for me:

```
python ./odoo.py -i module_to_test --log-level=test -d minimal_database --test-enable --stop-after-init
```

This is quite similar to what danidee answered.

However, the solution seems to be **not** to use the `--test-file` parameter, since this unexpectedly runs all tests of all dependent modules and does whatever else, making it too long to execute.

Another part of the solution is to use a minimal database where just the module to be tested plus its dependencies of course is installed.

Now the above command takes only several seconds to execute at my machine even if the tested code uses objects from dependent modules. If only I could prevent the module to make an update each time while running the tests in order to make it even faster and more efficient ...

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution. Odoo's update system and lack of proper migrations makes a lot of things tricky and sometimes impossible

Answer (score 3):

It's really difficult to do TDD with Odoo because most modules depend on other modules that still depend on some other modules and so on...

But what works for me is to have a custom module that installs all the other custom modules i've created,

This same module also contains all the tests for "anything custom" I've done on Odoo. Though you can place each modules tests within the module itself but I've had some problems when some tests didn't run for no reason. So i decided to place all of them in one module

so whenever i push a new commit. This is the command i use to run tests (assuming my module is named `all_modules`)

```
python odoo.py --addons=addons_path -i all_modules --log-level=test -d Test_Database --test-enable --xmlrpc-port=80xx --stop-after-init
```

Before doing this, I already have a Database (`Test_Database`) that's a clone of my production environment (so i can test against real Data) where the tests are run against.

For deployment i just use `rsync` and copy the files over.

My tests are reasonably fast (~5min) because i'm testing against a cloned DB and also because i'm only running tests for the custom modules I've built

I know this isn't standard TDD but Odoo doesn't conform to a lot of patterns in software development and most times you have to just strike a balance and find out what works for you.

Personally I've found `run-bot` too complicated and resource hungry.

PS: It's also helpful to have Selenium tests.

Comment: How to prevent Odoo to run test on 'core' modules? I just want it to do test **only** on my custom module (`all_modules`)

Comment: @VinhVO You can use --test-tags <your_module_name> to achieve this. When your tests inherit from Odoo common test classes, they are tagged with your module name. If not, you can tag them with odoo.tests.common.tagged(...) yourself.